# Regular Expression to validate the field: Field Data should not contain brackets

Tags: regex, validation, string

[dbo].Regex

above is my regular expression when i am passing '(' or ')'brackets symbol it is nt returnig error...

please hw 2 do this....

and please teach me how to eliminate perticular character is a invalid thing.
rite now wt ever symbol is present in brackets i.e [ ] its a valid so similarly how to eliminate the pericular words or letters.

Thanks in Advance.........

Please advise

Comment: You're missing a lot of vowels.

Comment: My god, is it that hard to type "how" and "to" instead of "hw" and "2"? This thing is unreadable!

Comment: And is that a '.' (a dot) I see in that pattern?

Comment: sorry friend......... i will not repeat this and thanks

Comment: @Moron: In that case, it's a literal dot since it's inside a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'^[-a-zA-Z0-9,&''.@#/:;]+$'`

- The first character `^` means start of string.
- Then everything between `[]` matches the characters allowed (in the string).
- The  `+` mean at least one such character is expected.
- The  `$` means, string end (so no other characters are allowed to follow).

To create a regular expression that is the inverse, there would be a `^` as first character between the  `[` `]`.

`[^()_]` Any character except  `(`, `)` or `_`

Warning: It can be that the curly brackets need escapes, similar as the above original regular expression showed with the `'`.

Have a look at this [quick start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), to get a good start on regular expressions.

Also the O'Reilly book [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570) is one of the references I would advise to read.

And on WikiPedia also good background on [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)s can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you're doing, but you can match everything *except* what's in the brackets of a regular expression by using `[^abc]` where `abc` are the characters you do not want to match.

Comment: '^[-a-zA-Z0-9,&''.@#/:;]+$' this is my actual regular expression....

My problem is, when i am  giving input to this regex with brackets(symbol '(',')') it is not returning Error Code.